# SLComposeViewController with screenshot but not image attachment

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, social-framework, slcomposeviewcontroller

I notice that Mobile Safari's Twitter and Facebook share adds a screenshot of the current page without actually sharing it, eg:

[image: Twitter Share from Mobile Safari]
[image: Facebook share from Mobile Safari]

Im trying to duplicate this via SLComposeViewController, however calling the [addImage:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) actually adds the UIImage to the tweet/facebook album (as expected).

Is there a way to just display the screenshot of the page without adding the image ?

Edit:
Looks like SLComposeViewController conforms to [UIAppearanceContainer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/UIAppearanceContainer_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearanceContainer) however the UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is previewing the screenshot to the website because it has it loaded and ready in on the screen, when you `addURL:` on the `SLComposeViewController` it doesn't resolve that URL and grab a preview.

Also when you `addImage:` that's exactly what it's doing, it's adding an image to your post, this isn't what you want, you just want to have a visual and not a safari logo/icon in place of the attachment indicating a link.

I can only say there is a private method on the `SLComposeViewController` class which is how Safari is adding a preview image for URLs added...

You should always get this in your app when sharing a URL:

[image]

That sucks, you should add a feature request (http://bugreport.apple.com) so that you can add your own preview here, maybe Apple will make that public in future iOS releases.

Comment: There is a solution to find in the source code of this page :http://open.spotify.com/track/3RgkkFF7fVp8N15neDqQOL
Cause when you use this url, the preview is different of the screen shot of this page